# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

When i type the username which is there in Table "fun" i am not facing any error but when i type wrong name that is the name which is not there in the table am facing error [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVuVe.png) and code is attached below.

```
    app.post('/Fu',function(req,res,next){

        var username = req.body.uname;
        var password = req.body.pwd;


         con.query('SELECT name FROM fun WHERE name = "' + username +'" ',function(err, result,fields) {


            var w = result[0].name;  

            if( username == w ){
         console.log("login successful");

         }
         else{
              console.log("login not successful");       
                   }
     }

});

           res.send("success1");
           });
```

can someone please help with the error.

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably related to the fact that, when username is not present in the table, `result` will be set to and empty array `[]`. That means that it has no elements at all, so `result[0]` is `undefined`.

Make sure to check for that before trying to get `result[0].name`.

Also, I would suggest you a few things:

1) Add error checking before anything else;

2) You do not need to check if the name is equal to the result. The query you wrote will only return entries that already match that requirement;

3) Send the responses inside the callback function, otherwise, the user will get the "success1" answer before the query has even finished executing.

Here follows the resulting code:

```
app.post('/Fu',function(req, res, next){
    var username = req.body.uname;
    var password = req.body.pwd;

    con.query('SELECT name FROM fun WHERE name = "' + username +'"', function(err, result,fields) {
        if (err) {
            response.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }

        if (result.lenght > 0) {
            res.send('Login was successful');
        } else {
            res.send('Login was not successful');
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working actually i knew how am getting error but unable to sort it out thank you once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

`var w = result[0].name;`

Because the result set at [0] doesn't exist (query came back with nothing). you are trying to get the `name` value from something that is `undefined`.

Do something like this:

```
var w
if (result[0]) {
    w = result[0].name
} else {
    //your logic to handle this scenario
}
```

That assumes that whatever db querying library you use will return an array, even if empty. If it returns `undefined` instead of an empty array, your `if` statement would need to look more like: `if (result && result[0])`